# Manipulando RadioButton para não ter valor em nenhum campo

Tags: javascript, razor, radiobutton

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês: eu tenho dois `radiobutton`, e eu queria transformar eles em `checkbox`, só eu não posso trocar o `type` para `checkbox`, neste radio eu poderia tornar para selecionar e para remover se quiser.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Muito cuidado com esses componentes "diferenciados", os usuarios estão acostumados com um padrão de funcionamento especifico de cada componente e eles vão exigir que esse padrão não mude... apenas uma dica .o.

Comment: @MarioAleo Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leonardo,

Coloque no onClick do seu radioButton uma dessas opções:

```
this.checked = false;
$(this).prop('checked', false);
$(this).attr('checked', false);
$(this).removeAttr('checked');
```

Se for colocado em um javascript separado você pode substituir `this` pelo `'#idRadioBtn'`

Também é possível buscando por todos elementos do tipo radio:

```
$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
$("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
```

As operações acima são para **desmarcar** o elemento selecionado, para fazer o contrário simplesmente troque os parâmetros `false` para `true`.

Talvez você precise de uma lógica de controle. Para verificar qual o estado do elemento use:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="nomeSeuRadio"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: não funcionou :\

Comment: Você colocou no evento de click?

Comment: @rafael sim eu coloquei

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo havia colocado exemplo para checkbox e não para radioButton, tente novamente...